# User created statistics adding dependency on columns on sql server

Tags: sql-server

Recently I have dropped all automatically created statistics (named `_WA_Sys_%`) and run the following T-SQL command to create statistics for all columns of the database :

```
EXEC sp_createstats @indexonly = 'NO', @fullscan = 'FULLSCAN', @norecompute ='NO'
```

All worked fine, until I had to drop a column in a table, then an `error 5074` occured, indicating that statistics should be dropped before dropping the column.

Is there a way to get `SQL Server` to drop silently user created statistics when a column is dropped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can make SQL server do it silently, as this is a common problem for people using user statistics. [There is a way to drop relevant statistics with a custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956620/do-statistics-referencing-a-column-prevent-that-column-from-being-dropped) - would it work for your needs?

Comment: Thank you for the link, the idea is good but the code was wrong. I have updated it.